# What is the easiest way to map NDC therapeutic class to broad condition?

Tags: data-request, medical

I have a list of NDC therapeutic classes (and individual NDCs) that I need to map to broader classes of conditions (like "diabetes" or "high cholesterol"). What is the easiest way to do this?

I could do something like this:
use http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/ndc/default.cfm to match NDC to drug name, then Google drug name to find condition.

Is there a better way?

Edit:

I found this site: http://www.ncqa.org/hedis-quality-measurement/hedis-measures/hedis-2013/hedis-2013-final-ndc-lists

That seems like I could use the linked excel files that map NDC to broad classes like "insulin."

Is there a way to use NDC classes?

Comment: How are you hoping to do mappings when drugs are used for multiple conditions? Are you looking to capture all the therapeutic indications for every drug?

Comment: I think that would be ideal, but I'm not sure. I'm trying to measure prescription drug adherence, and I was thinking that therapeutic class was not broad enough to capture true adherence since someone may switch to drugs in different classes in an attempt to treat the same condition.